# How to shut down the keyboard while a Selenium test is running

Tags: java, selenium, awtrobot

I am running long Selenium tests using Java. Some of the action include text typing using the Robot object. When those tests run I sometimes must stop using my keyboard, or preventing anyone from typing.

Is there a way to shut down or disable the user's keyboard while the Robot object is "stroking" the keys?

```
 Robot robot = null;
    try {
        robot = new Robot();
        checkKeyboardIsEnglish(robot);
        for (char c : textToType.toCharArray()) {
            int keyCode = KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(c);
            if (KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED == keyCode) {
                logger.error("Key code not found for character '" + c + "'");
            } else {
                try {
                    robot.keyPress(keyCode);
                    robot.delay(10);
                    robot.keyRelease(keyCode);
                    robot.delay(10);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    if (c == '_') {
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
                        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
                        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                    }
                    if (c == ':') {
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);
                        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);
                        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: There are utilities to disable/enable keyboard, see https://www.maketecheasier.com/disable-keyboard-windows10/

Comment: This is true, but I need Java code to help me do it, not a plugin or a utility.